# Why in all languages the word "samovar" is borrowed from Russian?

Tags: etymology

India, Iran, Turkey all have ancient traditions of samovar-making. Yet In Persian, Kashmiri and Turkish they call the device by a borrowed Russian word "samovar" (self-boiler in Russian). I wonder, why.

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever wonder whether it might be because the samovar is a Russian invention?

Comment: It is not, there are ancient samovars in India and Iran, attested long before the Russian ones.

Comment: Tea kettles yes; samovars no.